# Placing a WMS layer above a WFS layer makes WFS layer not selectable

Tags: openlayers, layer, geoserver, wms

I have two different layers which I call from Geoserver. The first one is a WMS layer with points and the second one is WFS layer with lines. I need to display the points above the lines and I also need to be able to select each line and get some data. I use the Openlayers2 library to display the layers on the map. I set the index of the WMS layer like this:

```
wms_layer.setZIndex( 1001 );
```

So I am sure it will appear on top when I display it from the layer switcher. But the problem is that when I make visible the WMS layer then the WFS layer is not clickable. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you adding layers to the page?

If you are doing `map.addLayers([WMS,WFS])` then try switching their order and see if that helps.